# New TextMate Templates Not Working

Tags: macos, textmate

I'm having an issue where if I create a new file based on an existing TextMate template, everything works great. However, if I create my own template, or even just duplicate an existing one, and then try and create a new document based on that template, nothing is created. The same happens when using the "test" button in the Bundle Editor.

I read an article about how this could happen if you're setting a path in your .base_profile, but I'm doing no such thing, and this only happens with NEW templates.

Any ideas on how to fix?

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual I find that answer not 10 seconds after asking the question. Apparently templates aren't saved and usable until you close the Bundle Editor, unlike snippets which are usable immediately.